# AspNetCore runtime error "Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported"

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I separated the AspNetCore controllers and views into an isolated .net standard 2.0 project which references the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc package.  The controller works correctly and the view cshtml can be found.

However, during run-time cshtml compilation, a large number of exceptions were thrown indicating some basic types were undefined such as System.String, System.Type, System.Void, etc.

*Error*

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HL7VCA4VNMOK", Request id "0HL7VCA4VNMOK:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
bbnqa23f.htw(4,62): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
bbnqa23f.htw(4,81): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
bbnqa23f.htw(4,109): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported
bbnqa23f.htw(4,11): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
bbnqa23f.htw(8,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
bbnqa23f.htw(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
bbnqa23f.htw(10,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
bbnqa23f.htw(11,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Does any one know how to solve this issue?

*Index.cshtml*

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

This is view
```

*Layout.cshtml*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

*Controller*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public class Startup : IStartup
{
    IConfigurationRoot cfg;
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        cfg = builder.Build();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app
        .UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "static")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/s")
        })
        .UseSession()
        .UseMvc(route =>
        {
            route.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action}", defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index" });
        })
        .UseSwagger(so =>
        {

        })
        .UseSwaggerUI(suo =>
        {
            suo.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Api Document");
        });
    }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var rlt = services
            .AddLogging(config =>
            {
                config.AddConsole();
            })
            .AddSession()
            .AddMvc(mo =>
            {
                mo.SslPort = 443;
            })
            .AddControllersAsServices()
            .Services
            .AddSwaggerGen(so =>
            {
                so.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API Document", Version = "v1" });
                var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Biz.xml");
                Console.WriteLine(path);
                so.IncludeXmlComments(path);
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider();
            ;
        return rlt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue after updating my solution projects from netcoreapp1.1 to netcoreapp2.0.  I am using Visual Studio 2017, and I had to do an update.

Control Panel --> Programs and Features --> Microsoft Visual Studio 2017
Right-click , select 'change'.  Was then prompted to allow and update.

Afterwards everything started working.  This was only for Web API projects, not sure if it applies to cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

For me this just happened in VS 2019, ASP NET Core 3.1 razor pages.

I was still in a Release configuration, not Debug (The last time I was in the solution I was publishing a release)

Switched back to Debug and Rebuilt solution.

Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Azure DevOps pipeline. The issue has gone after I updated nuget version from 4.4 to 5.10

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue just now after updating my bootstrap.

My solution was to simply add the layout statement at the top of my views:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

In _Layout.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Not sure how these were missing? They were definitely there previously. Maybe a weird VS 2019 bug that wipes out your layout statements when upgrading front-end libraries?